# Should we check the 'tense agreement'? If so, what' the difference in the meaning?

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses, tense-agreement

When we rewrite the passive-reporting verbs from one structure to another, should we check **the tense agreements**?　**'⇒'**are answers in text book, however, considering the tense agreement, **'*'** also seem to be fine. If so, what's the difference in the meaning?

1. The police confirmed that the man **will** receive a financial reward.
   ⇒　It was confirmed that the man **will** receive a financial reward.

- As for (1) is the following is also O.K?
  It was confirmed that the man **would** receive a financial reward.

2. Frank was known to **have been** a gifted musician at school.
   ⇒ It was known that Frank **was** a gifted musician at school.

- As for (2), is the following is also O.K?
  It was known that Frank **had been** a gifted musician at school.

Comment: Proof-reading questions ('Is this correct?') are off topic, so your question will probably be closed - but, yes, they are all correct.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @ Kate Bunting. I've edited my questions. I would like to know the difference of meaning if they( including *)  are all correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of your sentences are correct. In fact, your second sentence is arguably better than the textbook answer.

In this exercise, we are rewriting active sentences in the passive voice, removing the *agent* (the subject of the active sentence). The rules about *backshifting* in *reported speech* don't change between active and passive, so there's no good reason for the tense to change in the second example. The active version of the textbooks answer is:

> Frank was known **to be** a gifted musician at school.

Textbook answers should give the simplest possible answer so they don't confuse learners who might think that the rules for backshifting are different, which they're not. In this case, the textbook writer gave a totally correct version of the sentence, but not the best one, given the context of the exercise of translating a sentence from active to passive.